# How to Show "Radial Menu" jQuery Plugin at the Page Load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, menu

I am Not Familiar with JavaScript and i am beginner in jQuery!

I Found [RadMenu Pluging from web](http://tikku.com/jquery-radmenu-plugin#code_example_1) and want to use it to show my links as a Radial Menu: it is OK but I have a simple problem with it.

I want to know how can I "Load" (better to say "Show") Radial Menu at the `PageLoad` event?

I can `Show` or `Hide` the plugin with this code:

```
<a href="#" onclick='jQuery("#radial_container").radmenu("show")'>Show Menu </a>
<a href="#" onclick='jQuery("#radial_container").radmenu("hide")'>Hide Menu </a>
```

With this way user should click the anchor tag to view the Menu but I want to show it at the page load.

How can I Handle that?

Here is the JQuery and Plugin Options that I used:

```
$(function() {
            jQuery("#radial_container").radmenu({
                listClass: 'list',
                itemClass: 'item',
                radius: 100,
                animSpeed: 400,
                centerX: 30,
                centerY: 100,
                selectEvent: "click",
                onSelect: function($selected) {
                    alert("you clicked on .. "
                    + $selected.index());
                },
                angleOffset: Math.PI,
                onShow: function($menuitems) {
                    $menuitems.each(function(i) {
                        var $this = jQuery(this);
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            $this.fadeIn(500);
                        }, i * 100);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
addEventListener('load',
    function(){
        jQuery("#radial_container").radmenu("show");
    },
false);
```

If you wish to support IE too, use this instead:

```
addEventListener = window.addEventListener || window.attachEvent;
addEventListener('load',
    function() {
        jQuery("#radial_container").radmenu("show");
    },
false);
```

Comment: thank you but where should i place your code?! I placed it before above code(radMenu Initialization) and there was an error (Error: Object expected). if i use your code after above code there is no error but your event not working and the menu no showing.

Comment: This should be put after your code. It works just fine for me. What browser and version are you using?

Comment: i tested your code with chrome and it is ok, but it no working with IE8.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Try the second code sample and see if it works with IE.

Comment: unfortunatlly it is not working with IE. the Error message is clear: 'addEventListener' is undefined.

Comment: I have made a small mistake in the code. I've edited it to correct the problem; please try it again.

Answer (score 0):

since you're calling the initialization within document.ready ($(function(){})), all you have to do after instantiating it is call *.radmenu("show")*

essentially you will have:

```
$(function() {
    jQuery("#radial_container").radmenu({
            listClass: 'list',
            itemClass: 'item',
            radius: 100,
            animSpeed: 400,
            centerX: 30,
            centerY: 100,
            selectEvent: "click",
            onSelect: function($selected) {
                alert("you clicked on .. "
                + $selected.index());
            },
            angleOffset: Math.PI,
            onShow: function($menuitems) {
                $menuitems.each(function(i) {
                    var $this = jQuery(this);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $this.fadeIn(500);
                    }, i * 100);
                });
            }
    }).radmenu("show");
});
```